# Text mining, fact extraction, semantic analysis using .Net

Tags: .net, nlp, text-mining, semantic-analysis

I'm looking for any free tools/components/libraries that allow me to take anvantage of text mining, fact extraction and semantic analysis in my .NET application.

The [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk) project is what I need but it is written in Java. Is there something like GATE in the .NET world?

My challange is to extract certain facts out of website text content. I plan to use some NLP algorithms to achieve such functionality, but I'm not sure how do I implement them, so I'm gonna use any existing solutions if they were available.

I'll appreciate if you could give me some tips. I'm new in this area, so any related info would be very usefull for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a lot of success using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to port Java jars to .NET assemblies, you might try that out on GATE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Perhabs I'll try to port some GATE moduls to .NET if I don't get any native .NET library.

Comment: I've tried it out and successfully converted almost all .class files into one .NET dll. Thanks again, it's the best solution I've found by now.

Comment: Great!  One caveat is there may be some issues in an x64 environment.  Otherwise, we found performance to be much better for ported libraries than the native JVM - go figure.  Read more here - http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/2008/11/03/Bridging-the-Java-NET-Gap-foreach-ing-an-Enumeration.aspx